# Sort by tags - Redoc UI

Tags: swagger-ui, redoc

I have a swagger JSON where the tags are not in any particular order. I am trying to render this json in Redoc UI.  Is there any way to render Redoc Ui with tags sorted alphabetically.

```
Messages
   - API GET
   - API POST
   - API PUT
   - API DELETE
Filters
   - API GET
   - API POST
   - API PUT
   - API DELETE
Alarms
   - API GET
   - API POST
   - API PUT
   - API DELETE
```

Note: The same is possible in swagger UI with the below attribute

```
tagsSorter: "alpha"
```

I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Redoc uses x-tagGroups to group the tags and render them in the order.

For the above question
Adding x-tagGroups section to the swagger json file with the tags in the order we want them to be rendered in UI has resolved the issue.

[image]